# How to encrypt all partitions with BitLocker in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, encryption, bitlocker

My storage is separated physically into two SSDs (let's say `SSD 1` and `SSD 2`)

[image]

and logically into three partitions (`C`, `D`, `E`). I can encrypt the partitions `C` and `D`, that are stored on the `SSD 1`. But the partition `E` stored on `SSD 2` is not displayed in the BitLocker management view:

[image]

**What might be the reason? How to fix that?**

Comment: You will have to provide translation to English in order for me to submit an answer

Comment: If the partition E an NTFS volume? Besides that you can try to activate bitlocker via command-line using `manage-bde -on E:`.

Comment: @Ramhound Sure, I can do that. What exactly should I translate? But actually, it's just a standard Windows 10 BitLocker view.

Comment: @Robert Yes, it is. All three are NTFS. To the CLI: I would like to avid this way and handle all partitions via the GUI.

Comment: @automatix Your choice but if the GUI does not show the drive you won't be able. BTW: The screenshot you posed from the device manager is strange. Why is the device shown as SCSI system, is it connected to a RAID controller or something like that? Regular chipsets show connected SATA devices not as SCSI device. My guess is that the controller is somehow incompatible with Bitlocker and therefore the drive is not shown.

Comment: Hi @Robert, to "_My guess is that the controller is somehow incompatible with Bitlocker and therefore the drive is not shown._": Exactly. It's my guess as well. That's why it's almost impossible, that any non-GUI approach might help here.

Comment: @automatix Even if the approach will not work it might reveal an error message or an error code that allows you to better understand the problem.